# Socket.io does not connect when using $location.path() in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I want to use socket.io only at one section of my webapp. I use socket.io's set('authorization', fn) for handshaking the current context(express session and page-id). This works great when I refresh the current page, but does not when routing is handled by $location.path(url).

Socket.io code(view controller):

```
.controller('ViewCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $location, socket) {
  socket.connect('', { query: 'id=' + $routeParams.id });
  socket.emit('msg', { data: 'key'}); //DEBUG
  socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('Socket connected');
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('Socket disconnected');
  });
  ...
```

Routing code(main controller, frontpage):

```
if (data.owner == "yes") $location.path('/view/' + $scope.id());
```

Routing is of course secured server-side also.

Socket.io service:

```
.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
  var disconnecting = false;
  var socket = {};
  return {
    connect: function(url, query){
      disconnecting = false;
      socket = io.connect(url, query);
    },
    on: function(eventName, callback){
      socket.on(eventName, function(){
        var args = arguments;
        if(!disconnecting){
          $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          });
        }
        else {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        }
      });
    },
    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data, function(){
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
          if (callback) {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          }
        });
      })
    },
    disconnect: function(){
      disconnecting = true;
      socket.disconnect();
    },
    socket: socket
  };
});
```

I've also tried using socket.io directly in the controller(no service), same outcome.

The console does not give any errors either.

One solution is using socket.io for the whole app, communicating page-id, etc with emits. But this seem to be a waste when I only need socket.io at this "view-page".

**EDIT**:
This is where it goes wrong(should not have omitted this):

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function (event) {
  // disconnect socket when leaving page
  socket.disconnect();
});
```

Comment: Just adding that node does not output any socket.io handshake debugging messages, which is turned on.

Comment: Have you added console.log statements to your controller definition to be sure it's being instantiated (same with the factory)?  Also maybe drop in some debugger; line so chrome inspector will break in the  controller and factory to see that values are what you expect in each.

Comment: Yes, I've also tried debugging with console.log commands. Adding one above, and one below. Both outputting. I also checked that the socket var was saved(outputting the socket object to console). Though, my debugging skills stops there:/

Comment: You may want to check out the info on chrome debugging tools to see if something else will help... sounds like a very particular problem so will probably be hard to find a direct answer:https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging  Also watching the network tab while doing this stuff should reveal and calls to the server for ya.

Comment: Ok. That helps. I see no request in network console to /socket.io/nr/id when routing with $location, and socket.socket.connected is false. I'll poke around in the socket object to see if I find anything abnormal.

Comment: I think you may need to use $http.get("url") or $http.post("url",data) instead of $location, $location is updating the in browser URL but I don't believe it will ever cause an actual change in location (I may be wrong though)

Comment: $routeProvider is doing the actual change. Debugging helped me finding the solution, but my reputation is keeping me from posting it..I'll post it tomorrow. Anyhow, here it is: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/251

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Socket.io does not work in the manner connect() -> disconnect() -> connect().

When creating a one page app, io is always in namespace and socket is not removed from io.sockets. Therefor a new socket is not created at second connect().

Look at line 93 in socket.io client library:

```
if (options['force new connection'] || !io.sockets[uuri]) {
  socket = new io.Socket(options);
}
```

Solution, add 'force new connection':

```
var socket = io.connect('', { 'force new connection': true, query: 'id=' + $routeParams.id });
```

Thanks to [shaunhusain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509344/shaunhusain) for pointing me to Chrome debugging!

Reference: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/251

Comment: By using force new connection when ui-route change and then again come back to main page and select the other device to view the livetrack it can created both connection and i got two sockets data how to dissconnect the socket when ui-route change